Advice on my attempt to show $\ell^\infty$ with the sup norm is complete:
I have read a proof for this statement online and understand it entirely, however I would want to know whether my attempt as follows can be made to work with some guidance as to how I can continue it:
For $\ell^\infty$ with the sup norm:
For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|x^k - x^l\|_{\infty} < \epsilon$ for all $k, l > N$.
Each sequence $x^1, x^2, \ldots$ are bounded, and each has a convergent subsequence denoted by $x^1_{i_j}, x^2_{i_j}, \ldots$.
Each convergent subsequence converges to a limit $L_i$.
For all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $M^k \in (0, \infty)$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $|x^k_i| \leq M^k$.
For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\epsilon > \|x^k - x^l\|_{\infty} \geq \|x^k\|_{\infty} - \|x^l\|_{\infty}$ for all $k, l > N$.
Let $l = N$ and set $\epsilon = 1$.
There exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1 \geq \|x^k\|_{\infty} - \|x^N\|_{\infty}$ for all $k > N$.
There exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|x^k\|_{\infty} \leq M^N + 1$ for all $k > N$.
For all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $\|x^k\|_{\infty} \leq \max\{M^1, \ldots, M^{N-1}, M^N + 1\} = S$.
So the sequence $x^k$ is bounded by $S$ (but we cannot say for sure that it has a convergent subsequence as $\ell^\infty$ is an infinite-dimensional space, not of the form $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n$ is fixed).
So I have for each $x^k$, it converges to $L_k$.
I am not sure where to go from here, I want to construct a "guess" for a limit that the sequence (of sequences) converges to from which I can show actually works.
